# Is there a way to stop hidden text appearing when loading and then disappearing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains text that is selected dynamically using a drop down menu. When my page loads the text shows before disappearing once the page has fully loaded. Is there any way of stopping this happening? As i only want the text to appear once it has been selected.

HTML :

```
<select id="selectMe">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option> </select>

<div class="group" id="option1">asdf</div>

<div class="group" id="option2">Tilt.</div>

<div class="group" id="option3">zxcv</div>

<div class="group" id="option4">qwerty</div>
```

Jquery:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.group').hide();
$('#option1').show();
$('#selectMe').change(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
})
})
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Use CSS to hide elements on load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be hidden BEFORE your code runs. Use CSS:

```
.group { display: none }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply hide them by default:

```
.group {
    display: none;
}
```

Or, if you need them to still occupy block space (to prevent page "jumps"):

```
.group {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way round with JavaScript like this:-

```
document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML="asdf";
```

By using this you can keep the div(where the text is to be shown) empty in the starting so that there will be no chance of text being displayed before it is needed, and when a user clicks on the options then JS will just add this text to the div!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `innerhtml` to introduce the `display:none` rule to avoid to hide it even if jQuery/javascript is not avalaible .

basicly, in your head right before the body tag you can do this :

```
<script>
  var el=document.body;
  el.innerHTML = "<style>.group {display: none;}</style>";
</script>
```

It will hide the `.group` elements untill jQuery is loaded and effective.

If , for some reason javaScript is not avalaible, nothing will be hidden.

You can play with it here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/khbnp

Version with jQuery removed http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tjraw

Version without jQuery nor  javaScript http://codepen.io/anon/pen/disut actually shows what's hidden by previous version

Comment: Thank you, this is a great help!